# How to get a text file's encoding name by analyzing its byte in order to dynamically interpret it according to its Character encoding

Tags: c#, .net

```
   public string[] AbrirArquivo(byte[] Arquivo)
        {
            
            var arquivoTxt = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(Arquivo), Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")).ReadToEnd();

            var linhas = arquivoTxt.Split('\n');

            return linhas;
        }
```

I want to create a variable before the var arquivoTxt and store inside it, the value of  Arquivo's Character encoding. So I will replace the "utf-8" to my new variable, and then through this manner, my work will be completed.
The issue is, I don't know how to get the value of  Arquivo's Character encoding. Could any body help me out to solve this, please?.

Because many of the users aren't English speakers, The problem often is because many of them upload ANSI encoded files, then the special Characters get broken, and it sucks. I really need to find out a way to figure this out.

Comment: Fundamentally you can't do this accurately. *Every* file is valid ISO-8859-1 for example, but that doesn't mean that's the actual encoding. You could use heuristics (e.g. "if it's valid as UTF-8, I'll assume it's UTF-8") but it's definitely not guaranteed.

Comment: The closest built-in thing there is to this is [`IsTextUnicode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-istextunicode), which, as the name implies, only limits itself to guessing if it might be Unicode, and is well known for [making silly mistakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts). There may be more sophisticated third-party libraries to achieve this, but recommending any of those is off-topic for SO, and it'll still never be better than guesswork. The best approach is generally to tell people they can have any encoding, as long as it's UTF-8.

Comment: `when someone uploads an ANSI encoded file` you mean non-English. All codepages are identical in the range 0x00-0x7F. This range is represented in .NET by Encoding.ASCII. Above that range you can only use trial and error to discover whether your document contains characters that are invalid in one codepage or another. In the easy cases, trying to read a document using the wrong codepage will generate �, the Unicode Replacement Character, for every byte that has no corresponding character in the target codepage. In the rest of the cases you'd have to check for unexpected/uncommon characters

Comment: There are some libraries like `chardet` in C and Python, or [UTF.Unknown](https://github.com/CharsetDetector/UTF-unknown) in C# which try to determine the *probable* codepage based on conversion errors and the character frequencies in different codepages. The libraries provide an estimate of the best codepage. Whether that's correct or not depends on how good the algorithms are, how much training data was used and finally, how many user reported edge cases are covered by the library.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys very much, I did solve it!! Now it doesn't matter if they will unpload ANSI or UTF-8, it always gonna work.

```
` public string[] AbrirArquivo(byte[] Arquivo)
    {
        Boolean podeSerUtf8 = ValidaCodificacaoUTF8Arquivo(Arquivo);

        String codificacao = podeSerUtf8 ? "utf-8" : "Windows-1252";

        var arquivoTxt = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(Arquivo), Encoding.GetEncoding(codificacao)).ReadToEnd();
        var linhas = arquivoTxt.Split('\n');

        return linhas;
    }

    public Boolean ValidaCodificacaoUTF8Arquivo(byte[] Arquivo)
    {
     
        String text = null;
        UTF8Encoding encUtf8Bom = new UTF8Encoding(true, true);
        Boolean podeSerUtf8 = true;
        Byte[] preamble = encUtf8Bom.GetPreamble();
        Int32 prLen = preamble.Length;

        if (Arquivo.Length >= prLen && preamble.SequenceEqual(Arquivo.Take(prLen)))
        {
            try
            {
                text = encUtf8Bom.GetString(Arquivo, prLen, Arquivo.Length - prLen);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                podeSerUtf8 = false;
            }
        }


        if (podeSerUtf8)
        {
            UTF8Encoding encUtf8NoBom = new UTF8Encoding(false, true);

            try
            {
                text = encUtf8NoBom.GetString(Arquivo);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                podeSerUtf8 = false;
            }
        }

        return podeSerUtf8;
    }`
```